# How to make display icons with hdpi xxhdpi compatible for different mobile devices in ionic 3?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

How to make display icons with hdpi, mdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi compatible for different mobile devices in ionic 3 ?

How to actually code it that way ? Because there is a shift in text and picture sizes with other handset's displays.

Comment: Check provided docs here https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/cordova/resources